# Data Annotations are being ignored and/or not importing

Tags: c#, .net-core

So I'm starting a new project and when I use [Key] or [Required] I don't get the usual error/import message. I tried importing it manually and that has not helped either. Trying to figure out why they're not showing up. Did I miss a package? Thanks in advance

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; <- imported manually

namespace BookList_Razor
{
    public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you were missing packages, you'd get build errors.  Are you getting build errors? What do you mean by they are not showing up? There's little to go on with the sample you provided.

Comment: This looks like homework

Comment: Your question is _why am I not getting the usual errors?_